# On the definition of a module

Tags: group-theory, modules

Let group $G$ acts on the group $V$. Then there exists a homomorphism $\phi: G \longrightarrow {\rm Aut}(V)$. I want to know why we can consider $V$ as a module?

I saw this book: Gorenstein(Finite groups). He said that if there exists a homomorphism  $\rho$ of $G$ to  ${\rm GL}(V)$, then by definition

$$vx=v(\rho(x)) \ \forall v \in V,$$

$V$ is a $G$-module. Now i cant understand if there exists a  homomorphism $\phi: G \longrightarrow {\rm Aut}(V)$, then why $V$ is a module?

Comment: Assuming you have seen the term "module" in connection with rings, $V$ becomes a module for the group ring over whatever field $V$ is a vector space over.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft that is if $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$, then $V$ is a $F[G]$-module?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: here $V$ is multiplicative group, so we need to assume that $(V,+)$ is abelian group to say that $V$ is a vector space over the field $F$?

Comment: Changing $V$ from a multiplicative group to an additive group is just a change of notation. In other words, if $u,v,w \in V$ with $uv=w$ in the original multiplicative group, then $u+v=w$ in the corresponding additive group.

Comment: well, i means that $V$ must be abelian as a additive group, is it right?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft If $V$ is a vector space on $F$, then $V$ must be abelian, so i need to assume that $V$ is abelian in my question, is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think$V$ needs to be abelian for this to make sense. An arbitrary abelian group $V$, can be regarded as a ${\mathbb Z}$-module, so $V$ becomes a ${\mathbb Z}G$-module under the action.

But if $V$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group for some prime $p$ (i.e. abelian of exponent $p$), then we can consider $V$ as a module over the finite field ${\mathbb F}_p$ of order $p$, and so $V$ becomes a ${\mathbb F}_pG$-module under the action. This is useful, because it enables us to use results from representation theory, such as Maschke's Theorem, to deduce properties of the action.

Comment: If $V$ is not abelian, then $V$ is not a module?

Comment: If you look up the definition of an $R$-module $M$ on wikipedia for example, then you will see that it says that it is an abelian group $(M,+)$ under addition. If the original group $V$ was a multiplicative group, then we need to consider it as an additive group if we decide to consider it as a module.

Comment: Well, the term 'module' can be regarded as a synonym of group- (or even monoid-) '*action*'.

Comment: Really we must assume that $(V,+)$ is abelian? @ Derek Holt

Comment: Why do you keep repeating the same question?